# TextBox in Toolbar Eclipse RCP Application

Tags: java, eclipse, rcp, e4

I am trying to add a search field in the toolbar after my buttons of my Eclipse RCP Application from the Application.e4xmi , but it doesn't work. I created a ToolControl with a handler :

```
@Execute
public void execute(Shell shell) 
{

     shell.setLayout(new GridLayout());
        final Composite comp = new Composite(shell, SWT.NONE);
        comp.setLayout(new GridLayout());
        Text text = new Text(comp, SWT.BORDER);
        text.setMessage("Search");
        text.setToolTipText("search");
        System.out.println("i am in SearchToolItem ");


        GridData lGridData = new GridData(GridData.FILL, GridData.FILL, true, true);
        lGridData.widthHint = 200;
        text.setLayoutData(lGridData);
}
```

How should I do this?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you are specifying this class as a `ToolControl` in the e4xmi.

ToolControls don't use `@Execute` and they aren't given a `Shell`.

Instead use `@PostConstruct` and specify a `Composite`:

```
@PostConstruct
public void postConstruct(Composite parent)
{
   Composite comp = new Composite(parent, SWT.NONE);
   comp.setLayout(new GridLayout());

  ....
}
```

Note: Do **not** change the layout for the parent composite.

Comment: Now the toolbar appeared, but it gives me an exception: Unable to process "GoToLinkHandler#postConstruct()": no actual value was found for the argument "Composite".

Comment: Is this a ToolControl in the e4xmi or is it a command handler? This code only works for a ToolControl. Edit your question and put in exactly what you are trying to use.

Comment: It is a ToolControl

Comment: What do you mean by 'ToolControl with a handler'? This class should be specified in the 'Class URI' in the ToolControl definition.